# IDA - How to resolve "Write access to const memory detected" error?

Tags: ida, decompilation, error

I'm trying to analyze a binary that I unpacked, rebuilt, and dumped, using Scylla. After loading it into IDA and viewing pseudocode, I can see that there are errors where IDA tells me that it notices writes to constant memory addresses. After some searching online, I find that this seems quite common, but I haven't really come across a solution for fixing it, and I've just tried to ignore it up to now.

[image]

[image]

At first, I tried to just change all my segments to have write access, but that didn't seem to change anything. `0x007F944F` is the first memory error.

Would anyone mind telling me how I go about to solve this? Thank you.

EDIT: Here is the entire disassembly of that function:

```
.MPRESS1:007F93F2                     align 10h
.MPRESS1:007F9400
.MPRESS1:007F9400     ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.MPRESS1:007F9400
.MPRESS1:007F9400     ; Attributes: bp-based frame
.MPRESS1:007F9400
.MPRESS1:007F9400     sub_7F9400      proc near               ; CODE XREF: Stool__ctor+6F↑p
.MPRESS1:007F9400                                             ; Stool__ctor+91↑p ...
.MPRESS1:007F9400
.MPRESS1:007F9400     a3              = dword ptr  8
.MPRESS1:007F9400     u0              = dword ptr  0Ch
.MPRESS1:007F9400
.MPRESS1:007F9400 000                 push    ebp
.MPRESS1:007F9401 004                 mov     ebp, esp
.MPRESS1:007F9403 004                 cmp     ds:lpParameter, 0
.MPRESS1:007F940A 004                 jz      short loc_7F9410
.MPRESS1:007F940C 004                 xor     eax, eax
.MPRESS1:007F940E 004                 pop     ebp
.MPRESS1:007F940F 000                 retn
.MPRESS1:007F9410     ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.MPRESS1:007F9410
.MPRESS1:007F9410     loc_7F9410:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_7F9400+A↑j
.MPRESS1:007F9410 004                 push    esi             ; a2
.MPRESS1:007F9411 008                 push    offset sub_7F49C0 ; lpTopLevelExceptionFilter
.MPRESS1:007F9416 00C                 call    ds:SetUnhandledExceptionFilter
.MPRESS1:007F941C 008                 push    3DA4h           ; size_t
.MPRESS1:007F9421 00C                 mov     esi, eax        ; a2
.MPRESS1:007F9423 00C                 call    ??2@YAPAXI@Z    ; operator new(uint)
.MPRESS1:007F9428 00C                 add     esp, 4
.MPRESS1:007F942B 008                 test    eax, eax
.MPRESS1:007F942D 008                 jz      short loc_7F9438
.MPRESS1:007F942F 008                 mov     ecx, eax
.MPRESS1:007F9431 008                 call    StoolGuard__ctor
.MPRESS1:007F9436 008                 jmp     short loc_7F943A
.MPRESS1:007F9438     ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.MPRESS1:007F9438
.MPRESS1:007F9438     loc_7F9438:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_7F9400+2D↑j
.MPRESS1:007F9438 008                 xor     eax, eax
.MPRESS1:007F943A
.MPRESS1:007F943A     loc_7F943A:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_7F9400+36↑j
.MPRESS1:007F943A 008                 push    [ebp+a3]        ; a2
.MPRESS1:007F943D 00C                 mov     ecx, eax        ; a1
.MPRESS1:007F943F 00C                 mov     ds:lpParameter, eax
.MPRESS1:007F9444 00C                 call    sub_7F6610
.MPRESS1:007F9449 008                 mov     ecx, ds:lpParameter
.MPRESS1:007F944F 008                 mov     [ecx+10h], eax
.MPRESS1:007F9452 008                 cmp     eax, 755h
.MPRESS1:007F9457 008                 jz      short loc_7F9460
.MPRESS1:007F9459 008                 call    sub_7F4B00
.MPRESS1:007F945E 008                 jmp     short loc_7F9476
.MPRESS1:007F9460     ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.MPRESS1:007F9460
.MPRESS1:007F9460     loc_7F9460:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_7F9400+57↑j
.MPRESS1:007F9460 008                 cmp     ds:byte_8EB238, 0
.MPRESS1:007F9467 008                 jz      short loc_7F9476
.MPRESS1:007F9469 008                 push    offset byte_8EB238 ; lpString
.MPRESS1:007F946E 00C                 call    SToolGameGuard__Nop3
.MPRESS1:007F9473 00C                 add     esp, 4
.MPRESS1:007F9476
.MPRESS1:007F9476     loc_7F9476:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_7F9400+5E↑j
.MPRESS1:007F9476                                             ; sub_7F9400+67↑j
.MPRESS1:007F9476 008                 mov     eax, ds:lpParameter
.MPRESS1:007F947B 008                 mov     eax, [eax+18h]
.MPRESS1:007F947E 008                 test    eax, eax
.MPRESS1:007F9480 008                 jz      short loc_7F9489
.MPRESS1:007F9482 008                 push    eax             ; hEvent
.MPRESS1:007F9483 00C                 call    ds:SetEvent
.MPRESS1:007F9489
.MPRESS1:007F9489     loc_7F9489:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_7F9400+80↑j
.MPRESS1:007F9489 008                 mov     eax, ds:lpParameter
.MPRESS1:007F948E 008                 mov     eax, [eax+1Ch]
.MPRESS1:007F9491 008                 test    eax, eax
.MPRESS1:007F9493 008                 jz      short loc_7F949E
.MPRESS1:007F9495 008                 push    0               ; uExitCode
.MPRESS1:007F9497 00C                 push    eax             ; hProcess
.MPRESS1:007F9498 010                 call    ds:TerminateProcess
.MPRESS1:007F949E
.MPRESS1:007F949E     loc_7F949E:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_7F9400+93↑j
.MPRESS1:007F949E 008                 test    esi, esi
.MPRESS1:007F94A0 008                 jz      short loc_7F94A9
.MPRESS1:007F94A2 008                 push    esi             ; lpTopLevelExceptionFilter
.MPRESS1:007F94A3 00C                 call    ds:SetUnhandledExceptionFilter
.MPRESS1:007F94A9
.MPRESS1:007F94A9     loc_7F94A9:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_7F9400+A0↑j
.MPRESS1:007F94A9 008                 mov     eax, ds:lpParameter
.MPRESS1:007F94AE 008                 pop     esi
.MPRESS1:007F94AF 004                 mov     eax, [eax+10h]
.MPRESS1:007F94B2 004                 pop     ebp
.MPRESS1:007F94B3 000                 retn
.MPRESS1:007F94B3     sub_7F9400      endp
.MPRESS1:007F94B3
.MPRESS1:007F94B3     ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I'm not sure that decompiler generates correct code. Can you post the assembly code of the whole function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, `lpParameter` is located in a segment marked read-only (e.g. a code section), so the decompiler considers its value to be constant (probably zero) which is why all subsequent accesses are also zero-based. There are two solutions:

1. Mark the segment containing `lpParameter` to be writable (edit segment properties). In case the writable data is a small part of the otherwise read-only segment, creating a new segment just for data is a good idea
2. Mark only `lpParameter` as writable by adding `volatile` specifier to its type definition (use the <kbd>Y</kbd> key). In a similar manner, an otherwise writable variable can be marked as constant by adding a `const` specifier.

Reference: [Volatile and Constant memory](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/manual/tricks.shtml).

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. I will give this a try when I get an opportunity.

Comment: Option 2 is the only one that worked fully. I did try to create a new segment just for the data, but even though the writable flag was checked, it did not resolve it. However, option 2 works just fine for me. Thank you!

Comment: @Ci3: the segment name and class are also important, see the link.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see according to the decompiler output the program accesses not-existing (not created) segment at address 0x0. This may be a reason why it thinks that some memory is not writeable.
You can check this by creating a segment with r/w permissions at address 0 and size at least 0x20.

In addition as we can see from the full listing of the function the decompiler does not generate a correct code. All the accesses marked as `MEMORY[SOME_OFFSET]` should be relative to `ds:lpParameter`, not to 0.

Comment: Yeah, that does seem to make the `MEMORY` parts go away. I don't understand why it would be trying to write to address 0x0. What could be at that address?

Comment: That's why I asked in comment to provide the full listing of the function. I'm not sure that decompiler works properly. If I understand correctly the posted part of assembly code it should write to the same offsets related to lpParameter, not to 0.

Comment: Sure, I provided the full function. I agree, to me it seems it should write to offsets of `lpParameter`...

Comment: So, what value do you have in lpParameter ? Is it marked as offset ?

Comment: The value is a pointer to the struct I named `StoolGuard`. This struct's size is `0x3DA4`. I'm not sure what you mean by "is it marked as offset".

Comment: Oh I think I found it. It is marked as OFF32 - 32 bit full offset.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I marked lpParameter as volatile and this solved it.